# ASP.NET Core 6 appsettings.json with github secrets not working properly when deployed

Tags: c#, azure, github-actions

When deploying my application with GitHub secrets value my application can no longer authenticate and even though the values look the same for some reason its not working properly.

My `.yaml` file

```
name: Publish Application

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: my-service
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: "./publish"

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      packages: write
      deployments: write
      contents: read
      actions: read

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
        with:
          dotnet-version: 6.x

      - name: Restore dependencies
        run: dotnet restore

      - name: Build and publish
        run: dotnet publish --configuration Release --output ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}

      #substitute production appsettings entries to appsettings json file
      - name: App Settings Variable Substitution
        uses: microsoft/variable-substitution@v1
        with:
          files: '**/appsettings.json'
        env:
          VendorCredentials.vendor_id: ${{ secrets.VENDOR_ID }}
          VendorCredentials.username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          VendorCredentials.password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
          VendorCredentials.pin: ${{ secrets.PIN }}
          VendorCredentials.agent_id: ${{ secrets.AGENT_ID }}

      - name: Deploy to Azure
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
```

My code deploys successfully however whenever I hit an end point that is supposed to use these I get an error saying it can't authenticate.

This works locally however I have forced the error so I can see both log messages side by side. I am logging the creds to see the values this is what I am seeing

```
Local ENV:
"Error: Successfully Authenticate, Code: RESTAPI000 for user with vendorId vendorId with password myPassword with agent_id myAgentId with pin myApplicationPin failed to produce a token, please check the proper credentials are in the appsettings VendroCredentials section"

Azure:
Error: Invalid credentials!!, Code: RESTAPI001 for "user" with vendorId "vendorId" with password "myPassword" with agent_id "myAgentId" with pin "myApplicationPin" failed to produce a token, please check the proper credentials are in the appsettings VendroCredentials section
```

The values are exactly the same but in azure I am seeing that the values are in quotes. I have tried single quotes and double quotes and I get this exact behavior. If I save the secret with no quotes I get an internal server error and I don't even get to the logging part.

What am I missing?

Something to note in the deployment logs in github actions I am seeing the values replaced 3 times

```
App Settings Variable Substitution
Run microsoft/variable-substitution@v1
Applying variable substitution on JSON file: /home/runner/work/webform-myApplication/webform-myApplication/publish/appsettings.json
SubstitutingValueonKeyWithString vendor_id ***
SubstitutingValueonKeyWithString username ***
SubstitutingValueonKeyWithString password ***
SubstitutingValueonKeyWithString pin ***
SubstitutingValueonKeyWithString agent_id ***
Successfully updated file: /home/runner/work/webform-myApplication/webform-myApplication/publish/appsettings.json
Applying variable substitution on JSON file: /home/runner/work/webform-myApplication/webform-myApplication/webform-myApplication/appsettings.json
SubstitutingValueonKeyWithString vendor_id ***
SubstitutingValueonKeyWithString username ***
SubstitutingValueonKeyWithString password ***
SubstitutingValueonKeyWithString pin ***
SubstitutingValueonKeyWithString agent_id ***
Successfully updated file: /home/runner/work/webform-myApplication/webform-myApplication/webform-myApplication/appsettings.json
Applying variable substitution on JSON file: /home/runner/work/webform-myApplication/webform-myApplication/webform-myApplication/bin/Release/net6.0/appsettings.json
SubstitutingValueonKeyWithString vendor_id ***
SubstitutingValueonKeyWithString username ***
SubstitutingValueonKeyWithString password ***
SubstitutingValueonKeyWithString pin ***
SubstitutingValueonKeyWithString agent_id ***
Successfully updated file: /home/runner/work/webform-myApplication/webform-myApplication/webform-myApplication/bin/Release/net6.0/appsettings.json
```

Comment: Have you verified the updated `appsettings.json` that all secrets are populated correctly?

Comment: @Azeem I have logged the details and the only difference I am seeing is that the value is in double quotes or single quotes vs when I run it locally its all one big string.

Comment: `/home/runner/work/webform-myApplication/webform-myApplication/publish/appsettings.json`, `/home/runner/work/webform-myApplication/webform-myApplication/webform-myApplication/appsettings.json`, and `/home/runner/work/webform-myApplication/webform-myApplication/webform-myApplication/bin/Release/net6.0/appsettings.json` are three different files that's what you've configured `files: '**/appsettings.json'`.

Comment: Yes its replacing all the appsettings files which is totally fine since I only have one production environment if you are willing to do a zoom call so I can show you what I have I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The issue was happening because in the github secrets I was doing the following

```
AGENT_ID
"myAgentId"
```

After failing with that I did this:

```
AGENT_ID
'myAgentId'
```

Bot of these failed, what I should have done is

```
AGENT_ID
myAgentId
```

For some reason github is able to insert the entire value in quotes into the json file without breaking the deployment and that was the reason why when my code was running I was logging the value of the secret in quotes vs in my local environment.

If you are replacing values in a appsettings.json file you DO NOT need to save the secret in quotes, in fact that will break your code functionality, and will be harder to detect.

Thank you to all that took the time to read hope this helps someone in the future.

--Sinchiroca